# A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_blue'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I'm trying to add `flutter_blue` package to normal working flutter code on Android Studio(Windows) and getting an Error:

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_blue-0.5.0\android\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_blue'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.google.protobuf'.
   > Could not create an instance of type com.google.protobuf.gradle.ProtobufSourceDirectorySet.
      > 'void org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.gradle.api.internal.file.FileResolver, org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTreeFactory)'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 389

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_blue'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not create an instance of type com.google.protobuf.gradle.ProtobufSourceDirectorySet.
      > 'void org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.gradle.api.internal.file.FileResolver, org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTreeFactory)'
   > Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
   > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================
```

Here is `app\build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.project"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Here is project `pubspec.yml` dependencies:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_blue: ^0.5.0

  flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.2
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.3.2
  firebase_core: ^1.0.3
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.6
  dio: ^4.0.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^19.4.53
  path_provider: ^2.0.9
  path: ^1.8.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_platform_widgets: ^1.20.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
```